# Json response error when changing from webClient to httpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, httpclient, webclient

this question is with reference to [Convert WebClient to HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046196/convert-webclient-to-httpclient) thread. I am trying to convert WebClient to httpClient but receiving below error with the response json.

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Task' with type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder'1+AsyncStateMachineBox'1`

Please find my implementation below:

#### WebClient version

```
public static T GetFromApi<T>(string url, WebHeaderCollection headerCollection)
{
    T returnObject;
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        if (headerCollection != null)
        {
            client.Headers = headerCollection;
        }
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
        byte[] byteArray;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        returnObject = byteArray.DeSerialize<T>();
    }
}
```

#### HttpClient version

```
public static async Task<T> GetFromApi<T>(string url, WebHeaderCollection headerCollection)
{
    T returnObject;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw if httpcode is an error
            var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultString);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not understand where the self loop of json has been created, I am a beginner to .NET Core and C#, could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: First of all, why don't you use ```ReadAsAsync<>()``` directly? Second of all, which line the exception is referencing? Maybe you provided a ```Task<>``` as ```T```?

Actually, how exactly does this work? you ```await``` but the function is not ```async```.

Comment: This link might help you [Example](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/)

Comment: The provided code does not compile. The `await` operators require the `async` keyword in the method signature. Did you try `public static async Task<T> GetFromApi<T>(string url, ...)`

Comment: Please also bear in mind that you should not wrap the `HttpClient` instance into an `using` block. You should have 1 HttpClient / downstream system. Please read [this article](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) carefully.

Comment: Take a look at [Efficient api calls with HttpClient and JSON.NET](https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/) by [John Thiriet](https://johnthiriet.com/) for recommendations on how to pair Json.NET efficiently with `HttpClient`.

Comment: Your method originally had the signature `public static T GetFromApi<T>(string url, WebHeaderCollection headerCollection)` so you were probably doing `GetFromApi<Task<SomeConcreteType>>`.  Now that you have fixed the signature, you should do `GetFromApi<SomeConcreteType>(url,, headerCollection)`.